# Saving a stopwatch to access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am creating a virtual time clock so staff can track their hours throughout the month. The user will push a button on screen which will start/stop the timer as they clock in/out. Sample code for this function is below:

```
Private CAstopwatch As New Stopwatch
Private Sub timerca_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timerca.Tick
    Dim elapsed As TimeSpan = CAstopwatch.Elapsed
    CATimer.Text = String.Format("{000:00}:{1:00}",
                                Math.Floor(elapsed.TotalHours),
                                elapsed.Minutes)

End Sub

Private Sub CAButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CAButton.Click
    If CAButton.BackColor = Color.Silver Then
        CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red
        Timerca.Start()
        CAstopwatch.Start()
    ElseIf CAButton.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        CAButton.BackColor = Color.Silver
        Timerca.Stop()
        CAstopwatch.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works fine, but in case of the application closing I would like to save the information to an access database so it can be restored if need be.

At the moment I am just testing this with a push of a button to save the data which executes the following code

```
Private Sub TestButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TestButton.Click
    'connects application to database
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\DataPath\Database.accdb"
    Dim SqlString As String = "update SaintStaff set StaffHours = @CAHours, RecordedTime = @Time, RecordedDate = @Date where StaffName = @Staffname "

    'updates record in  SaintStaff table.
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAHours", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CATimer.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CurrentTime.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CurrentDate.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Staffname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CAStaff.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I can record the date and time without issue but I get a 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' error when trying to record the timer text. As a test I created a new label and set it so CATimer.Text = Label.Text, so when the timer updates it updates the label too. If I change the above code to save the label.text instead of CATimer.text it works. Obviously it doesn't like something about recording the timer but I dont know what. Anyone have any ideas?

Also instead of this update command being processed on a button push, is there a way to have this happen automatically say once a minute?

Thank you

Comment: What record are you updating? I don't see an insert.

Comment: Its not using an insert its using an update instead, I dont need to keep adding records just changing the one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always store date and time as *DateTime*, not text, and no reason to split this information.

So, change data type of *RecordedTime* to *DateTime*, skip _RecordedDate, and replace the two lines with one:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Yes, completely correct way to do it, I dont know why I was overcomplicating the situation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a mistake: the database field was set as integer, and obviously wouldn't accept a .text field input. I changed field type to text and it's resolved.

Comment: Text is the wrong type, too. Every successful time clock ever written has always used **DateTime** fields, and recorded only the TimeIn and TimeOut events.